# Inserting Hebrew text from thre querystring into a field value

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to take the value of a query string parameter, and insert it as a value of a field, but its coming out weirdly parsed.

URL with the query string: `activities.html?t=שלום`

Value of field comes out: `%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D`, (Whereas it should be: `שלום`.)

Code:

```
// access parameter using function below
var title = getUrlVars()["t"];   

// insert value into field: 
if (title) {
    $("#pdesc").val(title);
}


function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `decodeURI()` on your result, it should work.

Comment: Maybe update this to the context of the question. It would be helpful to see where to use decodeURI(). -> vars[hash[0]] = decodeURI(hash[1]);

Comment: Thank you, I did this in the end: `$("#pdesc").val(decodeURI(title));`